# Disable SQL Server at windows startup (VS 2010)

Tags: windows-7, boot, sql-server

After I installed Windows 7, booting lasted for about 40 seconds. Then I installed VS2010 and booting is 20 seconds longer. In task manager I see SQL Server process running. Is there a way to disable these programs at startup and fasten booting?

Answer (score 14):

You can control service startup in the services management console plug-in. Just:

1. **Start | Run**
2. Type `services.msc`
3. Press enter

You'll find various services with names starting with "SQL Server". Just double-click to get the Properties dialog, choose either **Disabled** or **Manual** in the **Startup type** drop-down box, and click **OK** to save. (**Manual** makes it easy to start them when you need them, but it also means VS 2010 can start them without asking you [I don't know whether it does that, I'm just saying].)

Comment: Or if the service is needed you can choose the **Automatic (Delayed Start)** option

Comment: I'd actually go for "manual", because you don't need them running the background all the time, but you want to be able to start them from a script at some point.

Comment: @Joel: Yeah, I was thinking that later. I've updated it.

Answer (score 3):

What I do in the services section is set the Startup type to manual.  Then I create a pair of batch files on my desktop.  In that batch file I place the following two lines:

```
NET START <Sql Server Instance Name>
NET START <Sql Server Agent Instance Name>
```

That way when I need to run SQL Server, I can quickly start it without having to back in through the Services panel.  Replace START with STOP in the other batch file to shut it down on command again.